Raikov Theorem about Poisson distributions.
I want to know more about the Poisson distribution and I searched that a statement is about the Raikov Theorem but I can only find the article in Russian and I can't read Russian.
Can any one tell me how to prove when the sum of two independent random variables is Poisson distribution and both of them are with the Poisson distribution, which seems the content of the Raikov theorem.Or can give me the paper in PDF?
Thanks in advance.

Similar question here.

@JeanMarie Yeah,but the page is 404 now, I have found it before.

It is accessible for me. Yes, it's the statement that if $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ are independent Poisson, so it their sum.

@vanderWolf So how to solve the inverse?(The two are independent), the page mentioned in its answer which contains the article is 404.

Do you mean: if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, and $X+Y$ is Poisson-distributed, then both $X$ and $Y$ are Poisson? (in case if they i.i.d. this trivially followed from the MGF).

@vanderWolf Yes,this is my question and how to prove it (when they are not i.i.d? )

Statement: Suppose $X,Y$ are independent, and $X+Y$ has a Posson ($\lambda$) distribution. Then $X,Y$ are both Poisson.
The statement is incorrect. Let $X-1\sim Poisson(\lambda/2)$ and $Y+1\sim Poisson(\lambda/2)$. Then neither $X$ nor $Y$ are Poisson,  but their sum is $Posson(\lambda)$.

I think you are right but I think this question means the original random variables are Poisson(X-1 and Y+1 in your case) rather than the X and Y(Otherwise thongh original is Poisson I can also add 1 or minus 1 to make it not). Otherwise the sum can be divided infinitely.Thank you for your answer and this is actually a theorem proved in 1930s(maybe I explain not so clear that mislead you).

According to Wikipedia, the variables can be "shifted Poisson", which I assume means Poisson plus/minus a constant. This allows your example.
